# RequestParam is null when CSRF security is enabled in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I have configured spring security + CSRF in spring cloud gateway.
I noticed that when the GUI calls an api which has @RequestParameter,the parameter is null and the server responds back as 400 bad request.

I tried call the same API but without the spring cloud gateway,i.e using the rest endpoint directly, it works fine.

I am not sure what is wrong.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

@Autowired
ProfileManager profileManager;

@PostConstruct
public void onInit() {
    profileManager.printActiveProfiles();
}

public static void main(String[] args) { SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args); }
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and()
           .headers(
                    headers -> headers
                            .frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions
                                    .mode(SAMEORIGIN)
                            )
            )
    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(getURLsForDisabledCSRF());
    return http.build();
}

private ServerWebExchangeMatcher getURLsForDisabledCSRF() {
    return new AndServerWebExchangeMatcher(
            CsrfWebFilter.DEFAULT_CSRF_MATCHER,
            new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(
                    "/grafana/**"
            ))
    );
}
/**
 * add csrf cookie response on every response
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public WebFilter addCsrfTokenFilter() {
    return (exchange, next) -> Mono.just(exchange)
            .flatMap(ex -> ex.<Mono<CsrfToken>>getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName()))
            .doOnNext(ex -> {
            })
            .then(next.filter(exchange));
}
}
```

below is my CSRF configuration in WebFlux(spring cloud gateway)

my api endpoint is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "terminate/{listName}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@CrossOrigin
@Loggable (activityname = ActivityLogConstants.DESCRIPTOR_TERMINATE)
public Response terminate(@Context HttpServletRequest reqContext, @PathVariable String listName, @RequestParam(value = "rowData") String rowData)
        throws ServiceException {
System.out.println(rowData);
}
```

request :
[image]
[image]

it does not work with @RequestBody as well. changed the code to `public Response terminate(@Context HttpServletRequest reqContext, @PathVariable String listName, @RequestBody(required = false) String rowData)`

Comment: and your request looks like?

Comment: Request URL: https://localhost:10443/cms-service/webapi/terminate/descriptor

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: eh? `@RequestParam` extracts value from the request, not the body. So your request should look like https://localhost:10443/cms-service/webapi/terminate/descriptor?rowData=SomeValue If you want the formData in the body you should use `@RequestBody`

Comment: it does not work with @RequestBody as well. changed the code to `public Response terminate(@Context HttpServletRequest reqContext, @PathVariable String listName, @RequestBody(required = false) String rowData) `

Comment: the requestbody is null

Comment: dont write code in comments, edit your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246681/discussion-between-toerktumlare-and-manjosh).

Comment: It works when queryparameters is sent in the URL like "https://localhost:10443/cms-service/webapi/terminate/descriptor?rowData=SomeValue". But just wondering how the old url works without spring security implementation